# Accesibility Compliance Error on keyboard access

Tags: javascript, html, standards-compliance

I'm trying to solve all the issues related to the 508 complianca and I'm struggling with on of them.

`Verify the <div> element with "menu" role has keyboard access`

How can I add keyboard access to don't see anymore that error ? I've been searching but I didn't find a solution for it

Basically the structure is the following, I have to added role values to that list. Is a sidebar with buttons on react js

```
<div role='menu'>
  <ul role='list'>
    <li role='listItem' />
    <li role='listItem' />
    <li role='listItem' />
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Menus are very specific things that require significant support for keyboards. Be sure what you are creating is actually a menu.

Read this to understand more about creating menus:
https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#menu

Comment: I've updated my question to tell you what structure is it